# How to use the echo command after a set /p command

Tags: batch-file, set, hidden

I wanted to make this script work somehow, but i find that after you use

```
set /p variable= whater you want here
```

If you use the echo command after it, its hidden or something because it wont come up...

```
@echo off 
cls 
color A 
:MAIN 
cls 
echo. 
echo. 
echo ================================= 
echo. set /p var= what is your name? 
:: DOES NOT SHOW UP (STARTING HERE) 
echo. 
echo ================================= 
:: DOES NOT SHOW UP (ENDING HERE) 
set /p answer= so your name is %var%? 
IF %answer%== yes echo thats an amazing name! 
IF %answer%== no goto MAIN
```

The part thats surrounded by the remarks doesnt want to show up for some reason... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do, this is the code you need:

```
@echo off  
cls  
color A  
:MAIN  
cls  
echo =================================  
echo what is your name?  
echo =================================  
set /p var=
set /p answer= so your name is %var%?  
IF [%answer%] == [yes] echo thats an amazing name!  
IF [%answer%] == [no] goto MAIN  
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the processor will wait for the user input after printing `what is your name?` (due to the `/p`), you will not get the next line of `========`etc. until enter is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

It shows up for me, I get

```
=================================
 set /p var= what is your name?

=================================
 so your name is ? Andy
```

Which is what I would expect, what are you expecting?